# Add a conversion constructor without touching class

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have two classes, from two different libraries, with the same meaning:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A&) {}
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const B&) {}
};
```

I want to call functions with `B` as parameter, passing an `A` object:

```
void setB(const B&) {

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A a;
    setB(a);
}
```

I know this is possible, adding a conversion contructor from:

```
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    B(const B&) {}
    B(const A&) {} // CANNOT ADD THIS!
};
```

But these classes are defined in two external libraries and I haven't rights to change them.

How can I add a conversion constructor (or achieve the same result) without touching the B class definition?

Comment: What you call as copy constructor above(*the one that you propose could be a solution*) in this case is actually a conversion constructor and not a copy constructor.

Comment: Write a function that takes an `A` as input and returns a `B`?

Comment: Do you have control over the functions? If so, you could make them `template` functions if the interfaces to `A` and `B` are identical.

Comment: I know I can add a converter function, but I'm asking if there is any way to call directly `setB(a)` without a converter `setB(toB(a))`, as if `B` had a conversion constructor.

Comment: You can provide an overload of `setB` that takes a `const A&`, and use that to construct the `B` and call `setB(const B&)`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **How can I add a conversion constructor (or achieve the same result) without touching the B class?definition?**

If the B class has a virtual destructor, you can specialize `B` and add the extra functionality in the specialization. If it does not have a virtual destructor, you can embed `B` in a wrapper class.

That means either:

```
class SpecialB: public B { // if B has virtual destructor
public:
    SpecialB(const A&); // you _can_ do this
};
```

or:

```
class SpecialB {
public:
    SpecialB(const A&); // you _can_ do this
private:
    B wrapped_b;
};
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for. It's an elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a factory:

```
 struct AfromB
 {
     static A convert(const B&);
 }
```

and:

```
 setB(AfromB::convert(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no access to `B` class definition, maybe the simpler is to have a `void setB(const A&)` overload.